# How to convert query to django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE 
'2016-08-05' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE()) 
OR 
'2016-08-11' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE()
```

Above is the query in mysql. How can I write this query in Django? **MyTable** is the name of the object in Django that maps to **mytable** table of MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easiest way**

Read about [Raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/)

```
MyTable.objects.raw(your_sql)
```

**More complicated**

Read about [QuerySet.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
MyTable.objects.all().extra(where="'2016-08-05' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE()) OR '2016-08-11' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE())")
```